# App crashes when starting it from Testflight Open button

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, testflight

I have an iOS project and in Debug mode, no crash at all.
When releasing the app to TestFlight, I launch the app from Testflight interface (with the open button), I get a crash.

If I launch the app from the iPhone home screen, no crash.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AppName                         0x100316b8c specialized AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift)
1  AppName                         0x100314284 @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x1863428a8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
3  UIKit                          0x186572094 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2904
4  UIKit                          0x186576500 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
5  UIKit                          0x186573674 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
6  FrontBoardServices             0x182b237ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
7  FrontBoardServices             0x182b23618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
8  FrontBoardServices             0x182b239c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181139124 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
10 CoreFoundation                 0x181138bb8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1811368b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
12 CoreFoundation                 0x181060d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
13 UIKit                          0x18633b834 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
14 UIKit                          0x186335f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
15 AppName                         0x100316388 main (AppDelegate.swift:18)
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x180bfe8b8 (Missing)
```

**EDIT**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    log.xcodeColorsEnabled = true
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    log.dateFormatter = dateFormatter
    #if DEBUG
      log.setup(.Debug, showLogIdentifier: false, showFunctionName: true, showThreadName: true, showLogLevel: true, showFileNames: true, showLineNumbers: true, showDate: true, writeToFile: nil, fileLogLevel: nil)
    #else
      log.setup(.Severe, showThreadName: true, showLogLevel: true, showFileNames: true, showLineNumbers: true, writeToFile: nil)
      if let consoleLog = log.logDestination(XCGLogger.Constants.baseConsoleLogDestinationIdentifier) as? XCGConsoleLogDestination {
        consoleLog.logQueue = XCGLogger.logQueue
      }
    #endif

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.mergeChanges(_:)), name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)

    //MARK: - Notifications registration
    remoteToken()

    if let launchOpts = launchOptions {
      let remoteNotification = launchOpts[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! NSDictionary
      if let notifFrom = remoteNotification["from"] as? Int, notifType = remoteNotification["type"] as? Int {
        let userid = notifFrom
        let type = notifType
        if type != MessageType.NotifyMsgType.rawValue {
          loadingChatUserId = userid
        }else{
          loadingChatUserId = nil
        }
      }
    }else{
      loadingChatUserId = nil
    }

    return true
  }

func remoteToken() {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() {
      //iOS 8 notifications
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil) )
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
  }
```

Comment: check this libdispatch.dylib file in project

Comment: You might have some code in the AppDelegate that you don't want to... Maybe post the file?

Comment: Good idea, I posted the didLaunchingWithOption delegate

Comment: Do you have push notification enabled in your AppID?
If you do,do you have both the developer/distribution push certificate?
Remember TestFlight works on a distribution level

Comment: I have push notification yes. I will check the push certificates!! Still how do you explain that starting the app FROM testflight interface OPEN button makes it crash but launching the app from Home menu works fine?

Comment: I checked. We have proper certificates and we can receive notifications. The only thing I can think of is that the the program spends too much time in the appdelegate and ios kills it for that reason... However, it really happens ONLY when we start the app through testflight interface

Comment: Did you find a problem? Looks like I have same issue with CoreLocation...

Comment: With recent updates (iOS or testflight I don't know) it doesn't crash anymore. Didn't change our program.

Answer (score 2):

```
if let launchOpts = launchOptions {
  let remoteNotification = launchOpts[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! NSDictionary
  if let notifFrom = remoteNotification["from"] as? Int, notifType = remoteNotification["type"] as? Int {
    let userid = notifFrom
    let type = notifType
    if type != MessageType.NotifyMsgType.rawValue {
      loadingChatUserId = userid
    }else{
      loadingChatUserId = nil
    }
  }
}else{
  loadingChatUserId = nil
}
```

Here is your issue... You're force unwrapping launch option as `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`. Use optional binding instead.

```
if let launchOpts = launchOptions {
    if let remoteNotification = launchOpts[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary{
        ....
    }
```

Comment: If I could give you 200 points, I would! Thanks a lot. This has saved my day.